# Need some assistance with understanding char->ASCII and some basics

Tags: c, project

I had a project to write this program that reads a character, integer and a floating number. It also had to convert the character in to its ASCII integer. I vaguely understand most of it except the code regarding the ASCII number. I created most of it on my own but when it came to converting the character I had a buddy help me, but he is not the best at explaining this.

Any explanation would be very helpful, thank you. I did this all by trial and error for... probably far too long :P

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

      char c;                       
      int i;
      float f;

      printf ("Please enter a character: ");
      scanf ("%c", &c);

      printf ("Please enter an integer: ");
      scanf ("%d", &i);

      printf ("Please enter a floating point number: ");
      scanf ("%f", &f);
      printf ("\n");

      printf ("The character you entered is: %c which is %d in integer-specification\n", c,c);
      printf ("The integer you entered is: %d.\n", i);
      printf ("The floating-point number you entered is: %f.\n", f);

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you not sure how the `printf` line that prints `c` works?

Comment: Essentially yes. Sorry, i didn't know how to explain it, but you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

It will be helpful to have a [reference documentation of `printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) handy.

When the format specifier is `%c`, `printf` expects an `int`. A `char` works since it is promoted to an `int`.

When the format specifier is `%d`, `printf` expects an `int`. A `char` works since it is promoted to an `int`.

For the first case, `printf` prints the character corresponding to the value of the `int`.

For the second case, `printf` just prints the number.

Comment: This is perfect. I thank you a million times! I will save that reference sheet, it will definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially a `char` is just an integer with a range from 0 to 255, the only thing that makes it a 'character' is that we have assigned characters to be represented by certain numbers.

What's going on in the `printf()` is that first you tell it that you're going to pass a `char` and would it please just output that byte to be displayed, then you say that you want it to convert an integer to a string and output that.

What it boils down to is that the ASCII code *is* the character.

Note: for reasons that are not important at the moment when being passed into a vararg function like `printf()` `char`s and `short`s are promoted to `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at explaining this.

Everything in a program memory is stored as sequences of 0s and 1s (binary numbers).  You are probably familiar with bits and bytes, but just in case: a binary digit (0 or 1) is a bit.  A sequence of 8 bits is a byte.  Characters, such as 'A', 'b', '1', etc. have to be stored as numbers in memory.  There are different ways to map a character to a number: EBCDIC (very rare these days, was used on large mainframes in the old days), UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 (types of Unicode), ASCII.  These mappings are called character encodings, and ASCII is the simplest of those commonly used.

So, when you enter a character, it gets stored in the variable c as an integer number encoded using ASCII.  The content of memory location corresponding to the variable can be thus viewed both as a character and an integer.

When using the printf() function you can request the same variable to be printed using different possible representations.  In this case, since c is a character variable and can be represented as a character or a number, you can use the different format specifiers, %c and %d, to have it printed as character and integer, respectively.

The 1st of the printf() calls above takes 3 arguments.  The first argument is a string that is printed out, with things that start with % being used to interpret the remaining arguments.  %c corresponds to the 2nd argument, %d to the 3rd.  %c says: "treat the 2nd argument as character and print it out."  %s says: "treat the 3rd argument as integer and print it out."

The other 2 printf() calls in your code take only 2 arguments.  The 1st argument, the string, contains only one thing starting with % (format specifier), so we only need 1 additional argument to be interpreted using the format specifier.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: It was very helpful. My professor isn't exactly thorough with his explanations, quite frankly he leaves it up to us to figure it out. But I think, as painful as it is, it's a very effective way to learn. Thank you for the help and information. Have a great one!

Answer (score 0):

the Man [ascii](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html) will make you understand